# The data is not added to the table even though the test was successful

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two entity and i testing my crud app. My test successfull but data does not appear in the table.

Isn't data added to the table when we use the test classes for Hibernate?

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)
public class UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest {

@Autowired
TestEntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
private UniversityRepo universityRepo;

@Autowired
private StudentRepo studentRepo;



// write test cases here

@Test
public void whenFindByName_thenReturnEmployee() {
    // given
    Students alex = new Students("ali",new Date());
    Universities kbuuniversity=new Universities("KArabuk uni",     "karabuk", "kbu.com", UniversityType.DEVLET, new Date());
    kbuuniversity.setApi_id(2);


    alex.setUniversity(kbuuniversity);
    kbuuniversity.add(alex);

    universityRepo.save(kbuuniversity);
    studentRepo.save(alex);



    // when
    List<Students> students = studentRepo.findAll();


    // then
    assertThat(students.size())
      .isEqualTo(1);

}

}
```

Entities:

```
/*
 * Students entity sınıfı.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="students")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value= {"created_at","updated_at"},
allowGetters=true)
public class Students{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

private String name;

private Date started_at;

//
@CreationTimestamp
private Date created_at;

@UpdateTimestamp
private Date updated_at;

//Üniversitenin tutulduğu değişken. Tablodaki university_id ile eşleşir.
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="university_id")
private Universities university;

//setters,getters,constructors...

}






/*
 * Universities entity sınıfı.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="universitiess")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value= {"created_at","updated_at"},
    allowGetters=true)
public class Universities{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

private int api_id;

private String name;
private String city;
private String web_page;

//devlet ve vakıf üniversitesi şeklinde iki tip barındaran enum.
private UniversityType type;

private Date founded_at;

@CreationTimestamp
private Date created_at;


@UpdateTimestamp
private Date updated_at;


//university parametresi Students sınıfındaki university adlı değişkeni işaret eder.
@OneToMany(mappedBy="university")
private List<Students> students;

//setters,getters,constructors...
}
```

Repository classes:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepo extends JpaRepository<Students, Integer>{

}


@Repository
public interface UniversitiesRepo extends JpaRepository<Universities, Integer>{

}
```

MariaDB [kodia-project]> SELECT * FROM universitiess;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [kodia-project]> SELECT * FROM students;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

Logs:

```
    20:17:50.603 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest]
    20:17:50.632 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
    20:17:50.659 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
    20:17:50.718 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper]
    20:17:50.765 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest], using SpringBootContextLoader
    20:17:50.777 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest]: class path resource [com/emr/kodi/KodiaSoftProject/EntityTest/UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest-context.xml] does not exist
    20:17:50.778 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest]: class path resource [com/emr/kodi/KodiaSoftProject/EntityTest/UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTestContext.groovy] does not exist
    20:17:50.778 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
    20:17:50.780 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest]: UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
    20:17:50.981 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest]
    20:17:51.249 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [/home/emrullah/Masaüstü/proje/KodiaSoftProject/target/classes/com/emr/kodi/KodiaSoftProject/KodiaSoftProjectApplication.class]
    20:17:51.251 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Found @SpringBootConfiguration com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.KodiaSoftProjectApplication for test class com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest
    20:17:51.254 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest]: using defaults.
    20:17:51.255 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
    20:17:51.322 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@4d826d77, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@61009542, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@77e9807f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@448ff1a8, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@1a38c59b, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@7f77e91b, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@44a664f2, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@7f9fcf7f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@2357d90a, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@6328d34a, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@145eaa29, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@15bb6bea]
    20:17:51.328 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest]
    20:17:51.329 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest]
    20:17:51.387 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest]
    20:17:51.388 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest]
    20:17:51.390 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest]
    20:17:51.390 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest]
    20:17:51.391 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest]
    20:17:51.391 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest]
    20:17:51.398 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: context [DefaultTestContext@2c34f934 testClass = UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@12d3a4e9 testClass = UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.KodiaSoftProjectApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@240237d2 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6b57696f, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@38bc8ab5, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@13c27452, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@5fda11dd, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@37374a5e], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
    20:17:51.399 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest]
    20:17:51.400 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest]
    20:17:51.409 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener - Performing dependency injection for test context [[DefaultTestContext@2c34f934 testClass = UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest, testInstance = com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest@23282c25, testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@12d3a4e9 testClass = UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.KodiaSoftProjectApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@240237d2 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6b57696f, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@38bc8ab5, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@13c27452, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@5fda11dd, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@37374a5e], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]].
    20:17:51.769 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils - Adding inlined properties to environment: {spring.jmx.enabled=false, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true, server.port=-1}

      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.2.RELEASE)

    2019-06-08 20:17:52.856  INFO 13814 --- [           main] e.k.K.E.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest : Starting UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest on emrozk with PID 13814 (started by emrullah in /home/emrullah/Masaüstü/proje/KodiaSoftProject)
    2019-06-08 20:17:52.864  INFO 13814 --- [           main] e.k.K.E.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    2019-06-08 20:17:54.354  INFO 13814 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
    2019-06-08 20:17:54.652  INFO 13814 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 250ms. Found 2 repository interfaces.
    2019-06-08 20:17:55.834  INFO 13814 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
    2019-06-08 20:17:56.196  INFO 13814 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
    2019-06-08 20:17:56.390  INFO 13814 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
    2019-06-08 20:17:56.523  INFO 13814 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
    2019-06-08 20:17:56.525  INFO 13814 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    2019-06-08 20:17:56.884  INFO 13814 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
    2019-06-08 20:17:57.183  INFO 13814 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    2019-06-08 20:17:58.443  INFO 13814 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2019-06-08 20:17:59.322  INFO 13814 --- [           main] e.k.K.E.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest : Started UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest in 7.551 seconds (JVM running for 10.581)
    2019-06-08 20:17:59.371  INFO 13814 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@2c34f934 testClass = UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest, testInstance = com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest@23282c25, testMethod = whenFindByName_thenReturnEmployee@UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@12d3a4e9 testClass = UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.KodiaSoftProjectApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@240237d2 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6b57696f, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@38bc8ab5, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@13c27452, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@5fda11dd, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@37374a5e], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@ca8ef3a]; rollback [true]
    Hibernate: insert into universitiess (api_id, city, created_at, founded_at, name, type, updated_at, web_page) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    Hibernate: insert into students (created_at, name, started_at, university_id, updated_at) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    2019-06-08 20:17:59.752  INFO 13814 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
    Hibernate: select students0_.id as id1_0_, students0_.created_at as created_2_0_, students0_.name as name3_0_, students0_.started_at as started_4_0_, students0_.university_id as universi6_0_, students0_.updated_at as updated_5_0_ from students students0_
    2019-06-08 20:18:00.054  INFO 13814 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@2c34f934 testClass = UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest, testInstance = com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.EntityTest.UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest@23282c25, testMethod = whenFindByName_thenReturnEmployee@UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@12d3a4e9 testClass = UniversitiesAndStudentEntityTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.emr.kodi.KodiaSoftProject.KodiaSoftProjectApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@240237d2 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6b57696f, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@38bc8ab5, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@13c27452, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@5fda11dd, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@37374a5e], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]
    2019-06-08 20:18:00.068  INFO 13814 --- [       Thread-3] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2019-06-08 20:18:00.078  INFO 13814 --- [       Thread-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
    2019-06-08 20:18:00.138  INFO 13814 --- [       Thread-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Comment: Can you please paste the logs here when you perform these operations? That will give us a better idea of what is happening while you are saving the entity.

Comment: i added the logs.

Comment: log shows: ... _[org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@ca8ef3a]; rollback [true]_   if you do'nt want a roll back after each test annotate your testclass with _@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)_ 
 ref: [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test)

Comment: Okey. Thank you.